# A fatso racist and a skinny racist jump off a cliff. Who wins?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, lateral-thinking

A fatso racist and a skinny racist jump off a cliff. Who wins?

Rhymes from a place where dreamers can express their dreams with verse,

> *...I was afraid to start writing....*
>
> *...hearing them is one thing voicing them is another...*
>
> *...she looked at me and took her time before saying...*

The Theory of Humans,

> *That Man to Man is a kind of God; and that Man to Man is an arrant Wolfe.*

---

Hash:

D5ACFD8330F5CAAEE7D1421788C912DC9C5DA654BBC226A904798D1A30DE9953

Salt:

84B03D034B409D4EE1F53135E559C253

---

Answer (score 6):

This is a joke answer

A fatso racist and a skinny racist jump off a cliff. Who wins?

> The answer of course is the human race, who are glad to have two more racists in the grave.

Comment: At first, I wanted to be fully sure of what was meant by "who wins"... but now I know: It means, (ROT13) jub jvaf gur ENPR? :D